# Angular 2 CLI SCSS inline images

Tags: node.js, angular, sass, angular-cli, scss-lint

I'm re-coding a site originally wrote in Compass, but I use a lot of inline base 64 images with ***inline-image*** now I'm using Angular 2 CLI with node-sass but that function is not available, there's a library named sass-inline-image but it needs gulp configuration and I'm not sure where to put it, someone knows how to fix this?

Comment: a quick fix might be converting/embedding the image manually using vanilla css like this `url(data:image/gif;base64,...) ` Maybe [this article](https://css-tricks.com/data-uris/) can help